# Creating a dropdown menu from a list in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column in excel of the following form:

| Column 1 |
| --- |
| ['a', 'b', 'c'] |
| ['d', 'e', 'f'] |

I want to create a dropdown menu in each cell of the column where the possible options are the elements in the list. The elements in the list are sorted and would prefer that they remain that way on the menu. Is it possible to this on excel?

Comment: You could use TEXTSPLIT on them to create a SPILL range somewhere else in the file and refer to that in your list reference. For instance `=B1#` if `B1` contains `=textsplit(A1,{"[","'",", ","]"},,1)`